# Wordpress - Upload Woocommerce Product Pictures Automatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have looked around and didn't find any plugin to help me upload pictures directly to it's related product:

Say we have a woocommerce product with the reference:

**sk01**

and two images

**sk01_1.jpg** and **sk01_2.jpg**.

I would like a plugin to help me load those images automatically to the respective product. (could be matched by name as well)

Is there anything like that?

Obs: The sk01_1.jpg could be set as featured image by default.